# datetime picker is not showing

Tags: asp.net, .net

i want to add a date time picker in my code. the code i have is:-

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
   =======scriptmanager========
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  ==========column where i want to add date time picker=======
    <td>Date Of Birth*</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtdate" value="" MaxLength="50" size="30" Style="width: 170px; height: 20px;"></asp:TextBox>

                            <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="txtdate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtdate" Format="dd-mmm-yyyy">
                            </cc1:CalendarExtender>

                        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have registered it and you uses the correct `TagPrefix` there's only one thing that comes to my mind that you could check.

Try to use the `ToolkitScriptManager` instead of the `ScriptManager`.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="true" ScriptMode="Release" EnablePartialRendering="true" AsyncPostBackTimeout="1000" CombineScripts="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" EnableCdn="false" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="false" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

I've just added my configuration(without `ScriptReference`s).

Comment: i  used toolkitscrpitmanager but it is showing that toolkitscrpitmanager is not a known element.

Comment: It is ToolkitScriptManager.

Answer (score 0):

There are trends to stop using Ajax Control Toolkit.

Try to use jQuery DateTime picker instead: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/